# how to save battery in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: jupiter

Am using a laptop so need efficient use of battery, so that i can get long backup.
i have seen some videos that shows we can use jupiter applet and save our battery but when i try for my laptop there is no result please help me with this.

Regards,
Rajesh Jana

Answer (score 1):

[TLP](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html) is a good alternative for Jupiter.

You can install it by typing the following commands into the terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

Just restart the system and you're done. There are no specific settings you need to do to make TLP work. Just install and forget.

Answer (score 0):

"Jupiter Applet has been retired and is no longer supported software." (from sourceforge).

Try `powertop` instead. There have been some reports of some of the tweaks being suboptimal, but in general it works well.

Also have a look at what services you have running, you may find you don't need all of them - SQL servers for example, some apps will install one & you won't want it always on.